# gnome: how to execute commands upon screensaver activation?

Tags: gnome, dbus

is there a way to run a specific command every time gnome-screensaver is activated?

thanks

Comment: must be a hook or a dbus event. or you create a custom screensaver that lauches your command. http://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found there : http://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html#gs-intro

Gnome Screensaver has a Dbus Signal named :

```
ActiveChanged
```

in

```
org.gnome.ScreenSaver
```

then call

GetActive()

and if it returns true you call your method